# In form alter change the allowed value list programatically of select box defined using admin content type

Tags: 7, forms

I have added a select list field using admin ui in a content type and I want to alter allowed value list and fill dynamically in form alter in drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

I think last solution won't work because drupal has a mechanism to verify between allowed value and submitted value for field type list. Please see here for more information, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21list%21list.module/7

I found below solution.Please replace field name with yours,

```
function test_form_node_gallery_item_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $options = system_region_list('commons_origins', $show = REGIONS_ALL);
  $all_fields_all = field_info_fields();
  $all_fields_all['field_region_list']['settings']['allowed_values'] = $options;
  field_update_field($all_fields_all['field_region_list']);
  $options = system_region_list('commons_origins', $show = REGIONS_ALL);
  $form['field_region_list']['und']['#options'] = $options;
}
```

It will work like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

After little bit googling, you can easily get answer of this question. Any how, you need to execute this with **#after_build**, something like following code.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'mymodule_action_after_build';
}

function mymodule_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['your_field_name']['value']['#options'] = array("Allowed options value");
  return $form;
}
```

More info: https://drupal.org/node/726282

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [Content Construction Kit (CCK)](https://drupal.org/project/cck) module. After installing this module you get a text field for Allowed value function in field setting of desired field. Put the function name here to get country list. Also put following function in a module.  You may have to modify query as per your requirement.  After doing all these thing you will able to get country list in that field.

[image]

```
function _get_country_list(){
    $country = array(); 
    $query = db_select('country', 'c');
    $query->fields('c', array('country_name','country_id'));
    $result = $query->execute();    
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
            $country[$row->country_id] = t($row->country_name);
        }
    }
    return $country;
}
```